# Power BI Underlying Data Export Issue

Tags: powerbi

I have an admin rights but still I am not able to download underlying data. "File Format" option getting disabled while selecting Underlying Data option and getting blank excel/csv file.

please help to get of this problem.

[image: Screen shot of Export data panel showing "xslx" option is disabled]

Answer (score 0):

I can see two options:

1. The dataset is situated in another Workspace where you don't have adm rights.
2. Your dataset is in the same Workspace as the report. In this case, you have to enable build permissions on the dataset.

More info on building permissions: https://www.fourmoo.com/2019/10/08/power-bi-bulk-changing-permissions-read-reshare-build-on-datasets/

Comment: I have the same issue. Dataset in the same workspace. And I am the Owner (=> have All Permisssions)

Comment: Isn't it about the report permissions? Try going to the report settings: 

File -> Options and Settings -> Current File -> Report Settings and in Export Data tick the box 'Allow end users to export summarized and underlying data from the service'

Comment: If you don't have necessary permissions, you can't select "Underlying Data" Tab then. In this case you can select tab, but can't choose file format